# I have a multiple option select which populate data from MySQL but select first element from html. I do not want to store first element in db

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

This is the html form multiple select list. list option are populated from database. But when I submit the form it also stores `<option value="0">Select multiple options:</option>` if I select it. I just want that either it is selected or not it should not be stored in db. Thanks in advance.

```html
<p>
  <label for="stu_courses">Courses:</label>
  <br/>
  <select id="stu_courses" name="stu_courses[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">Select multiple options:</option>

  </select>
</p>
```

```html
function setdbSelect() {
        $result1 = Plusql::from($this->profile)->courses->select('*')->run()->courses;
        foreach ($result1 as $value){
        echo $result1->course_id;
        }
        $options = array();
        foreach ($result1 as $value) {
            //$this->template->setValue('#stu_courses', $result1->course_name);
            $options[$result1->course_id] = $result1->course_name;            
        }
        
            \Config\Central::repeat_select_options($this->template, "#stu_courses", $options, 0);
        
    }
```

Comment: So check if value 0 has been submitted and remove it from the data you insert. Where's the problem?

Comment: Good approach that you are suggesting but I have done it by using if condition. if $value>0 works for me. But thanks for the comment.